# Why I can not navigate my Jenkins EC2 instance? This site can’t be reached

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

I looked at various SO answers
My EC2 security groups

[image]

I also tried to ping,got this

```
PING 54.197.186.213 (54.197.186.243) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 54.197.186.213 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

I logged in console,says jenkins could not be found
[image]

What should I check now?

Comment: Have you try with browser on port 8000? About `ping` - it is not permitted by security rules

Comment: @RomeoNinov Both Chrome and firefox,no help.

Comment: Do you have jenkins started on the instance?

Comment: @RomeoNinov No,please take a look at my newest edit.

Comment: It seems that me Terraform apply didn't work as expected.

Comment: Richard, in such case you must install jenkins package, then start it and then try to reach the web interface